# installing envariorments for windows phone 8 with mobilefirst 6.3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

Hello im trying to run a mobilefirst 6.3 hybrid app with a windows phone 8 environment in it working with windows 8.1 profesional,

In the documentation says that i mus install visual studio 2012 for windows phone 8, that visual studio doesnt exist now, so wich visual studio / tools ive must install to run this proyect.

because ive install visual studio express 2012 for windows 8 with the windows phone sdk 8 and when ive run the environment the visual studio says:

```
csproj cannot be opened because its project type is not supported 2012
```

which  visual studio i ve  must install  in a windows 8 SO.

is visual studio 2013 supported ?  which version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Visual Studio 2013 is supported.
Use Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: what about visual 2012, is not supported now?

Comment: not if you're developing for newer releases of windows phone. Use the new VS.